# Laravel function with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel

In my web file, I have a route that accepts a $id as a value to be passed to a function within my PagesController. However, I want the function to still execute and show the intended form even when the $id is not passed to the function.

web.php file

```
Route::get('/request/{id}', 'PagesController@makeRequest');
```

PagesController.php file

```
public function makeRequest($id)
{
   if(!empty($id)){
      $target = Partner::find($id);
   }
   return view('pages.makeRequest')->with('target', $target);
}
```

makeRequest.blade.php

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$target->inst_name}}" required disabled>
```

I want the page to display details from the database with the $id when provided or have empty spaces when the $id isn't provided.

Comment: Would https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters help? (And don't forget to make your method parameter optional/give it a default)

Answer (score 15):

As the Laravel Documentation states: Use [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) like this:

```
Route::get('/request/{id?}', 'PagesController@makeRequest'); //Optional parameter
```

Controller

```
public function makeRequest($id = null)
    {
        if(!empty($id)){
            $target = User::find($id);
            return view('pages.makeRequest')->with('target', $target); 
        } else {
            return view('pageslist'); ///set default list..
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried it and I got an error.
```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::makeRequest(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: did you pass id in your url?

Comment: I want it to work both for instances, ie. variable passed or not.

Answer (score 3):

All your solutions were helpful. The main thing was that when I called just the view without passing $target to the view, the page displayed an error. So this is what I did.

```
Route::get('/request/{id?}', 'PagesController@makeRequest');
```

Then in the controller,

```
public function makeRequest(Request $request, $id=null)
    {
        if ($id != null) {
            $target = Partner::find($id);
            return view('pages.makeRequest')->with('target', $target);
        }
        return view('pages.makeNullRequest');
    }
```

If you didn't understand what happened, I created a new view which had this instead of what I had posted in the question.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" required readonly>
```

Sorry I didn't update you guys in time. I think Jignesh Joisar came closest to helping me solve this issue. really appreciate all you guys. You're just awesome

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I did it:

```
  Route::get('index', 'SeasonController@index');
```

// controller

```
 public function index(Request $request )
    {
        $id= $request->query('id');
    }
```

The way you call it:

```
localhost/api/index?id=7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) parameter  :

```
Route::get('/request/{id?}', 'PagesController@makeRequest');
```

Now, as the parameter is optional, while defining the controller function you need to assign its default value to `null` in argument declaration.

```
<?php 

public function makeRequest($id = null)
{
   if($id){

        $target = Partner::findOrFail($id);

        return view('pages.makeRequest')->with(compact('target'));
   }

   // Return different view when id is not present
   // Maybe all targets if you want

   $targets = Partner::select('column1', 'column2')->get();

   return view('pages.all')->with('targets');

}
```

I am using [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) instead of `find`. Its Laravel's very handy function which automatically throws a `ModelNotFound` exception and for frontend user throws a simple 404 page.

So if anyone is accessing `www.url.com/request/2`, its a valid id then it will show a valid page with data. If the accessed url is `www.url.com/request/blahblah` then it will throw 404. It avoids efforts of handling this manually.

Answer (score 1):

For optional parameter pass id with ? in route and give $id = null in your function's parameter like this:

```
Route::get('/request/{id?}', 'PagesController@makeRequest'); //Optional parameter

makeRequest($id = null) {

// Code here...
...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your routes file (web.php , as mentioned in your question)

```
Route::get('/request/{id?}', 'PagesController@makeRequest');
```

and in your controller PagesController.php

```
public function makeRequest($id = null)
{

}
```

To read more about this, just read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was in the order that I listed the Routes in the routes file.

The routes file will call the first one that matches the pattern.

```
Route::get('/ohmy/{id?}', 'OhMyController@show');
Route::get('/ohmy/all', 'OhMyController@all');   //never gets called
```

Instead, put optional parameters at end of list:

```
Route::get('/ohmy/all', 'OhMyController@all'); 
Route::get('/ohmy/{id?}', 'OhMyController@show');
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer has been said. just a side note: optional parameters won't work if you are using resource routes.
for example:

```
Route::resource('items',itemController::class)->except([
    'create',
]);

Route::get('/items/create/{category_id?}',function($category_id = 'abc'){
    dd($category_id);
});
```

if i go to " items/create/1 ", the result will be "1".
if i go to " items/create ", it will return 404. ( but we expect it to say "abc".)

this happens because other routes that start with "items" are expected to be generated from "resource" functionality.

so if you use resource routes, you should consider that.